How to use CSS to Style for Smart TVs
How can I use CSS to apply a specific set of styles for Smart TV browsers?
Looking for something like a user agent detection, or similar. I use display width and aspect ratio to detect mobile browsers currently.
Context:
My specific use case is one with a site divided into two divs (left and right). The right div is supposed to scroll, and the left div displays content fit to the viewport.
Smart TVs tend not to be able to scroll correctly, nor do they like rendering scroll bars. I can work around this by just making both divs the same height (since TVs seem to be able to scroll the whole page, just not a single div at a time). I don't want to enforce rendering scroll bars wholesale as devices with touch screens don't need them, and they clutter a phone screen unnecessarily.
Anyway, I have some options, but I can't figure out an easy way to determine if the rendering browser is a Smart TV.

not reliably. but try this and use it to maybe set add a tv class for the body. Change CSS accordingly.
